# how to count the two count function's return value in once sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three tables A,B,C.Their relation is A.id is B's foreign key and B.id is C's foreign key.I need to sum the value when B.id = C.id and A.id = B.id ,I can count the number by query twice. But now I need some way to count the summation just once time !

#### My inefficient solution

```
select count(C.id) from C,B where C.id = B.id;  //return the value X
select count(A.id) from C,B where A.id = B.id;  //return the value Y
select X + Y; // count the summation fo X and Y
```

How can I optimize ? Thks! :)

#### PS：

My question is from [GalaXQL](http://sol.gfxile.net/galaxql.html),which is a SQL interactive tutorial.I have abstract the problem,more detail you can check the section 17.SELECT...GROUP BY... Having...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do these things in one query.  For instance, something like this:

```
select (select count(*) from C join B on C.id = B.id) +
       (select count(*) from C join A on C.id = A.id)
```

(Your second query will not parse because `A` is not a recognized table alias.)

In any case, if you are learning SQL, the first thing you should learn is modern `join` syntax.  The implicit joins that you are using were out of date 15 years ago and have been part of the ANSI standard for over 20 years.  Learn proper `join` syntax.

Comment: +1 for mentioning proper join syntax. I hate it when I have to look at the WHERE part of the statement, to determine the join conditions!

Comment: select count(A.id) from C,B where A.id = B.id;

Can you please tell what is A.id is that you have two tables A,B

Comment: @Ramya . . . I think that is a question for the OP and should be on the question.  I assume the code is just a typo.

Comment: Yeah.by mistake posted here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your tips.I really need to focus join and sub-query syntax learing.They are both make me head hurt!

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
select sum(cid) (

select count(*) as cid from C join B on C.id = B.id
union all 
select count(*) as cid from A join B on A.id = B.id ) as tt
```

Comment: Thks! It's useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

***try this one:***

```
select 
(select count(*) from C join B on C.id = B.id) 
union
(select count(*) from C join A on C.id = A.id)
```